# How to arrange the selected options depends on user selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Does anyone knows how to arrange the selected options depends on user selection? for example the user selected options 3, 1, 4, and 2?

```
 var selected_id = [];
        $(document).on('click','.clickable',function(e){
          if(selected_id.length>=1 ){
            selected_id=[];
          }

        $(this).parent().find(":selected").each(function(){
          selected_id.push($(this).attr('id'));

        });

        console.log(selected_id);
        }).get().join(", "); 
        $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault();
             $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url('reports/generate_imported'); ?>",
                data: {selected_id: selected_id},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            }); 



            return false; 

         });
```

here's my view page

```
     <select class="form-control reports" name="cols[]" multiple="multiple" id="cols[]" required="required">
                    <option id="1" class="clickable" value="1">item 1</option>
                    <option id="2" class="clickable" value="2">item 2</option>
                    <option id="3" class="clickable" value="3">item 3</option>
                    <option id="4" class="clickable" value="4">item 4</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:  [Link Example](http://jsbin.com/fipana/edit?js,console,output)

```
var selected_id = [];
var selected_ord=[];
            $(document).on('click','.clickable',function(e){

              var ops= $(this).parent().find(":selected").length;

             if($(e.target).is(':selected')){


             selected_ord.push($(e.target).attr('id'));

     selected_id=selected_ord.slice(selected_ord.length-ops, selected_ord.length);          

             }


         else {

               var toRemove=selected_ord.lastIndexOf($(e.target).attr('id'));

             selected_ord.splice(toRemove ,1);
           var index = selected_id.indexOf($(e.target).attr('id'));  
           selected_id.splice(index, 1);

         } 

              console.log(selected_id); 



            }).get().join(", "); 
            $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                 $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url('reports/generate_imported'); ?>",
                    data: {selected_id: selected_id},
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });    



                return false; 

             });
             $("#gen-btn").click(function(){
                selected_id.length = 0;
             });
```

Comment: @En E el someone may find it useful here